# Unable to route to correct port (:8069) within Google compute engine

Tags: google-compute-engine, odoo, odoo-11

I have set up a Google compute engine VM with an accounting program "odoo" installed, which runs a Postgresql database/web server. I'm now trying to allow external web connections too the web portal, which I can access from http://myworkaddress.com.au:8069 with no problem. However I would like it to be accessed by simply http://myworkaddress.com.au and not have to specify the port number.

I would have thought this would be a simple route redirect and have tried loading an "rc.local" file in /etc with

"iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 80 -j REDIRECT --to-port 8069"

However this does not work. I've also tried setting up routing rules within the compute console, but these don't work either. Clearly I've got the firewall correctly set up otherwise I would not be able to reach the web page with the port number added to the address.

I'm sure that I've missed something simple here, but I have searched everywhere with no "answers which work.

Next step after achieving the correct routing will be figuring out how to secure the connection over a SSL link.........

Thanks in advance for any help.

Steve

Answer (score 0):

Either: Configure `odoo` to use `:80` [link](https://www.odoo.com/forum/help-1/question/how-to-change-the-default-port-8069-used-by-odoo-server-60679)

Or: Check whether IP(v4) forwarding is enabled on the instance ([link](http://www.ducea.com/2006/08/01/how-to-enable-ip-forwarding-in-linux/)), you'll need this enabled (reboot) before the `iptables` change will be effected.

Ensure your firewall rules permit `80/tcp` to the instance(s) and a good rule is to be as specific as possible.